# MVC, Render HTML page which includes AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, rendering

I have a site build in MVC5 and C#. In this site I have a view (public.cshtml). In this view I have some text and beneith this text I would like to render another view (angular.html). The anguar.html view contains some angular script. How do I render the html page in the cshtml page correctly? Or is it even possible?

I have tried using Partial, RenderPartial and RenderPage but with no succes.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether your public.cshtml is "covered" with `ngApp` or all angular-related stuff is in that "angular.html".

If it's the first, you could use [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude):

```
<ng-include src="'/...'"></ng-include>
```

if it's the latter, you could use [`@Html.Raw()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.118).aspx), like this

```
@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/...")))
```

where "..." is your relative path to angular.html.

Comment: Thank you! I had to create a div around the @html.Raw to define the ng-app the view should use: `<div ng-app="tournamentApp">
        <div>@Html.Raw(File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Apps/Modules/angular.html")))</div>
    </div>`

Comment: If you're using `ng-app` outside that html, then you can go with `ng-include` - just replace your `@Html.Raw` with it. It's less verbose.